# Export to Pdf and Export to Image for Kendo Charts not working in IE9/Safari

Tags: jquery, pdf, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

// I am using chart id to export to pdf for kendo charts and it's working fine // on Chrome and Firefox but it's not working for IE9 and Safari 
// This is the button where I click to Export it to PDF

```
<button class="k-button export-button bar-control" id="export-pdf-button-onedimension" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Export as PDF" onclick="exportChartToPdf('chart1');"></button>
```

// This is the function where I am passing the chartid for exporting it to PDF

```
function exportChartToPdf(chartId) {
    $("#" + chartId).getKendoChart().exportPDF({ paperSize: "auto", margin: { left: "1cm", top: "1cm", right: "1cm", bottom: "1cm" } }).done(function (data) {
        kendo.saveAs({
            dataURI: data,
            fileName: "chart.pdf"
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Older browsers such as IE9 and all versions of Safari require a proxyURL to be used since they can't save files locally.  See kendo documentation on Chart PDF  http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-pdf.proxyURL

Comment: Thanks Robin but I am unable to redirect it to the action in the controller even after using proxyURL.

Comment: thanks it worked finally